# Netbeans profiler produces warning

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler

Whenever I profile a project this message pops up:

> Profiler Agent Warning: JVMTI classLoadHook: class name is null.

I want to know if this is harmful or this could be ignored.

Comment: It looks harmless, see https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252031 and https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=246383